# Limit as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ for $\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^6}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, wolfram-alpha

I want to show that the limit $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ is $0$ for $$\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^6}$$

I wrote it as $$\frac{\frac{x}{y}x^2y^3}{(x^2)^2+(y^3)^2}$$ We know $x^2<\sqrt{(x^2)^2+(y^3)^2}$ and $y^3<\sqrt{(x^2)^2+(y^3)^2}$.

Therefore, it seems like it is of the form $\frac{x}{y}(\text{bounded function})$. But clearly, $\frac{x}{y}$ is not bounded, and so we can't say $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}$ is $0$. However, Wolfram Alpha says that the limit will be $0$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Showing that the limit $< \frac x y$ doesn't say that the limit is infinity, just as $3 < \infty$ doesn't say that $3$ is infinite.

Comment: My suggestion is to use polar coordinates.

Comment: Let $u=x^4+y^6$. Then $|x^3|\le u^{3/4}$ and $|y^2|\le u^{1/3}$. What do these say about the whole expression?

Comment: How did you get those? $|x^3|\le u^{3/4}$ and $|y^2|\le u^{1/3}$ @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Don't you agree that $x^4\le u$ etc.?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah! I see. I do

Comment: Is it possible to generalize this to $\frac{x^a y^b}{x^c+y^d}$ ? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: @Blue Yes, read about homogeneity of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Courtesy of [Lord Shark the Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471676/limit-as-x-y-to0-0-for-fracx3y2x4y6#comment5106982_2471676).

---

More generally, consider

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|^a|y|^b}{|x|^c+|y|^d}$$

Now define $u=|x|^c+|y|^d$ and see that

$$u\ge|x|^c\implies u^{a/c}\ge|x|^a\\u\ge|y|^d\implies u^{b/d}\ge|y|^b$$

Thus

$$0\le\frac{|x|^a|y|^b}{|x|^c+|y|^d}\le u^{\frac ac+\frac bd-1}$$

So if

$$\frac ac+\frac bd-1>0$$

Then the limit must be zero.