# Limit of multivariate fraction in the shape of Young's Inequality

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

We are asked to determine the conditions s.t the following limit exists. We need to determine an inequality with a,b,c,d s.t. this limit exists. However, I am unsure on how to proceed. I thought about choosing a path of $f(x, mx^z)$ but even then I don't know how to proceed. Any help would be appreciated! :)
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{|x|^a|y|^b}{|x|^c + |y|^d}$$

Comment: Have you tried polar coordinates?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2471846/108128